# Create news update with comments, how to join tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a news update system, using MySQL and PHP. But i can't get it working, having trouble with the join satement and PHP, so i can display a news update and all the comments attached (and if a valid user is logged in, the person can delete each comment individually). But it is only the JOIN statements i'm having trouble with.

I have these tables and DB schema

1. news_tbl (news_id, date, user (fk to users_tbl.username), headline, bodytext and picture)
2. users_tbl (username, email, password, usertype)
3. comments_tbl (comments_id, name, comment, news_id(fk to news_id))

I have tried with this:

```
$sqlquery ="SELECT news_tbl.*, users_tbl.*, comments_tbl.*,
COUNT(comments_tbl.comments_id) AS comments_count
FROM news_tbl
LEFT JOIN users_tbl
ON news_tbl.user = users_tbl.username
LEFT JOIN comments_tbl
ON comments_tbl.news_id = news_tbl.news_id
GROUP BY news_tbl.news_id ";
```

But then i can only display one comment, and i want all the comments, and i want to fecth the ID of each comments, so the user can delete each comment individually. And also i cannot get a news id, if a comment isn't written?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [What have  you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: yes.. please share your query.. ies...

Comment: @Charles ... *doppelganger!*  I spent about thirty seconds starting at your comment, wondering why I posted that while also not fixing the OP's silly formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This should get roughly what you want,although you should always share your query and also specify exactly what you pretend to achieve.

```
Select ut.user_id,nt.news_id,nt.headline, nt.body,ct.comments_id,
ct.comment,count(ct.comments_id) as total
from news_tbl nt
inner join users_tbl ut on ut.user_id=nt.user_id
left join comments_tbl ct on ct.news_id=nt.news_id
group by ut.user_id,nt.news_id
```

good luck.

Comment: @user1906437 try `left join comments_tbl ct on ct.news_id=nt.news_id` instead.